# Build router for nested routes

Tags: php, router

I want to create a router that allows me to work with nested routes. something like this

```
$router = new Router();

$router->get('/', function() use ($router){
    // i want to create an object here
    $router->get('/segment1', function() use ($router) {
        echo 'im in /segment1';
        $router->get('/segment2', function() use ($router) {
            // and maybe use that object here
            echo 'im in /segment1/segment2';
        })
    })
})
```

And i also like to have wildcard segments
Please note that the code is not working is just an example of what i want to have. thank you

Comment: Not really sure what issue is from your description. This may be better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  If you are only working with concept code and aren't having a programming issue, then your question is off topic.

Comment: Code Review. good idea ;)

Comment: @Crackertastic: I have just closed a similar question, which appeared to ask for new implementation and not a code review.  Even this particular question is off-topic on CR, and the last sentence reveals that.  Please take extra care when recommending CR in comments.  [Here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is our Help Center.

Comment: Just edited the CR for the working code so i cant get review for that. i will try to find the way of using nested routes in the router banging my head. thank you

Comment: @Jamal My apologies, I did indicate that concept code was off-topic.  But now that I am re-reading my comment I do appear to "exclude" CR from that notion - which was not my intended delivery.